# What would be the order of energies and wavelengths of photons emitted from different electronic transitions?

Tags: atomic-physics, photon-emission

When an electron from fifth orbit falls down to first orbit, then it emits a photon of wavelength (lambda ) in [Lyman region of spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series).

But if an electron jumps from fourth orbit or third orbit to first orbit, then what would be their wavelengths and energies? Would they be higher in energies than  energy of photon from fifth orbit transition?

I think energy of photon from fifth to first orbit transition would be greatest because of greater energy gap between first and fifth orbit. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Although I think this is more of a question for Chemistry Stack Exchange, it is one that can be answered here. Still, I recommend you put it on CSE for a better insight into how it works.
Now, we know that when the electron travels from one stationary orbit to another it releases energy in the form of photons. The wavelength say $\lambda _1$ of the photon is given by:
$$\lambda _1 = R_H \Bigl(\frac{1}{n_i^2} - \frac{1}{n_f ^2} \Bigl)$$ 
where $R_H$ is the Rydberg constant and $R_H \approx 109779$ cm. Now just looking at it you can see that the denominator will be large for the higher orbit, thus we see that the $\lambda_1$ is decreasing for the transition from higher $n_i$. Also we see $$E= \frac{h \cdot c}{\lambda1}$$ 
So, $$E \propto \frac {1}{\lambda 1}$$ 
Thus, the $E$ is highest for a transition from $n_i = \infty$ to $n_f = 1$ and $ \lambda_1$ is lowest for this transition. This line is also called limiting line.